# Machine Learning: quantifying uncertainty around missing data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, missing-data, uncertainty, quantify

My question is around a specific classification problem I have.

My training data is complete and doesn't have missing data. I can build any classification model around it (SVM, Random forest, etc.) to give good results. So far pigs are not flying in the troposphere.

The problem is I want to **apply these models to data with missing features**. I am not interested in imputation of any sort. I would like an "uncertainty" measure that goes up the more missing features there are, and I still want the model to spit out a result (even with high uncertainty). For example for one record, if 5 out of 10 features are empty data, the model would give a class but with an uncertainty of 50% (ideally I can specify how "important" each variable is).

I haven't run into anything similar online, and I've been looking for a while.
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why is it data specific question?

Let us start with very simple model - a linear one (`f(x) = sign(<w,x> + b)`). Let us also assume that we are now given a vector with missing value `x_i=N/A` and that corresponding weight is non-zero (`w_i != 0`); without loss of generality let `w_i>0`, then we can see, that I can always "imput" `x_i` so small (very, very negative value, like `-10e10000`) that the model will answer `-1` and symmetrically, so large value that it will output `+1`. In order to make a prediction (and further - quantify the certainty) we do need an assumption of possible values of `x_i`. I hope that this simple example shows, that without any assumption we are lost - we cannot do anything, no predictions, no certainty - nothing. This is a very well known fact in machine learning - we cannot have a prediction without a model induced bias. In this case - we model missing values.

### What can we do?

We need to agree what the values can be. There are many options:

- we can assume uniform distribution, for example if it is a categorical variable with M values, we put 1/M probability on each possible instance. If it is something between 0 and 1, we can use a uniform distribution on such range. In such scenario we **need bounded values**. If values are unbounded - there is no uniform distribution.
- we assume some infinite support distribution, for example a simple Gaussian, which is either arbitrary (0-mean, 1-std) or learned from data (empirical mean + empirial std).
- we infer some complex distribution, maybe using non-parametric estimator (KDE) or maybe even conditional distributions infering from other dimensions.

Ok, how is it different from data imputation? Data imputation assumes filling a missing value, it gives you a **point**. What I am talkin about here is to think about our point with missing values as a **probability distribution** - so more Bayesian approach. Now it is no longer a data-point, it is an infinite cloud of point, with various densities.

### How to apply classic ML technique on distribution?

Unfortunately, here things become complex, as it is **completely model specific question**. So depending on what type of classifier/regressor you use - you need different approach. The simpliest case would be Random Forest, so I will focus on this one, and later give a less efficient, but more general solution for any model.

#### Random Forest case

In decision trees, each node is a decision on some feature. So in order to make a prediction on our "distribution" we simply put the point into the decision process - if node asks about existing feature - we process it normally. What to do when we are asked about missing feature? We split execution, and compute **both** paths, but with weights computed from out distribution and the threshold in the node. For example, let us assume we have choosen an uniform distribution on [0,1], and threshold is now 0.75 (meaning that this node asks whether a missing value is <0.75 or >=0.75). We split computations and check prediction in both parts, the one with <0.75 decision gets weight 0.75 (as it is an integral `INT_{0}^{0.75} pdf(x) dx`, where `pdf(x)` is our uniform distribution) and the second path gets weight 0.25. At the end we get the expected value. What is our confidence? You compute is as usuall, or perform more complex analysis of confidence intervals.

#### General method

The most general method (which can be used for any model as a black box) is a Monte Carlo method. We have our distribution `pdf(x)`, so we repeat sampling from this distribution, classify and record the output. At the end - we gather votes and get both classification and confidence. Pseudocode follows

```
function CLASSIFY_WIT_NA(x, probability_model, model, k=1000):
  pdf <- probability_model(x.missing_values)
  predictions <- empty set
  for i=1 to k
    x' ~ pdf
    prediction <- model(x')
    predictions.add(prediction)

  class <- most_common_element_of(predictions)
  confidence <- count(class, predictions) / k
```

Comment: Fantastic answer ! Thank you :) Do you know of any package that handles distribution for missing values in Random Forest in python or R ?